# Help please i cant login to wordpress panel

Tags: wp-admin

I purchased a daomain from namecheap i was trying to use it for my wordpress site , "using mamp" but now when i try to login to my wordpress panel it does not work

Comment: "It does not work" isn't helpful, you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no reason you should be paying for a domain for a site run in MAMP. MAMP lets you run WordPress on your local computer, but the site is not accessible over the internet, so you can't give it a domain name.

If you just want a nicer URL for your personal use locally, then you still don't need to buy it. Just add the domain to your [hosts file](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_use_the_hosts_file/) for your local IP and you can use it.